# How to delete iTunes Music folder from command prompt on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, itunes

If I have to delete the music folder of iTunes on a Windows PC, is it possible to do it from the command prompt? If so, how?

Comment: You just want to delete the music (not the iTunes itself) ? Is there a specific reason ?

Comment: Yes only the list of music because I have a lot of old music that I don't like it anymore

Comment: @BryanSavian What do you mean by prompt commands? Do you mean Windows terminal DOS commands?

Comment: Yes I mean Windows terminal DOS commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **The best way to remove your music is to do it directly from iTunes** :

  1. Open iTunes and navigate to `Library` > `Songs` ;
  2. Press `ctrl`+`A` to select all your music ;
  3. Right click on the selection and choose `Delete from Library` ;
  4. Select `Delete Songs` and then `Move to Recycle Bin` ;
  5. Empty your Recycle Bin.
- **If you absolutely want to do that from the Command Prompt** (I don't know why, and be aware that iTunes will remember the music after that) :

  1. Open the Command Prompt as administrator (by right-clicking on Start icon and selecting `Command Prompt (Admin)`);
  2. If your iTunes folder is not on the `C:` drive type `D:` (for drive `D:`) and hit `ENTER`. Navigate to your iTunes folder using `cd \path\to\iTunes\"iTunes Media"\` then hit `ENTER` (don't be into the Music folder. If you are type `cd ..`);
  3. To remove type `rd Music \s \q` and hit `ENTER` (`\s` is for removing subdirectories and files, `\q` is for skipping confirmation);